# Android WebView shouldoverrideurlloading does not call for JavaScriptMethod

Tags: javascript, android, webview

I have a webview and loads a webpage and after loading the page. I call for javascript method and send some data. After that the call, the javascript method call for ajax request to another link and sends some data to server. It does not enter the shouldoverrideurlloading method. How can handle this.
Android WebView shouldoverrideurlloading does not call for JavaScriptMethod

```
webView.loadUrl(command); // Command = javascript method
```

Comment: Can you share how exactly how call the javascript command. I mean I want to see the command portion.

Comment: webView.loadUrl("javascript:submit('" + json + "')";

Comment: What settings have you set in webView?

Comment: webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

Answer (score 0):

Add this is in webView setting

```
mywebView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
```

Comment: I'm using webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() { ..... What is the difference